# How to add load more button at the end in MUI component autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a simple functionality, there is data that is loaded during the opening in autocomplete, and there are a lot of them, and need to add at the end of the button load more, searched for solutions, could not find a suitable, do you know how to do it?

I try use template in MUI docs:

```
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-filled"
        options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
        freeSolo
        renderTags={(value: readonly string[], getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option: string, index: number) => (
            <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
          ))
        }
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="filled"
            label="freeSolo"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried the example ?